# Why don't works $emit and $on?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

CoffeeScript:

```
Vue.component 'levels-list',
    template: '#levels-list-template'
    props: ['uuid', 'type']
    data: ->
        {
            element_levels: []
            other_levels: []
        }
    mounted: ->
        @getElementLevels()
        return
    methods:
        getElementLevels: (uuid) ->
            if typeof uuid == 'undefined'
                uuid = @uuid
            _this = this
            $.get "/ajax/elements/#{uuid}/element_levels.json", (data) ->
                _this.element_levels = []
                _this.other_levels = []
                $.each data.element_levels, (i, element_level) ->
                    _this.element_levels.push(element_level)
                    return
                $.each data.other_levels, (i, other_level) ->
                    _this.other_levels.push(other_level)
                    return
                return
            return

        switchLevel: (uuid) ->
            @getElementLevels(uuid)
            levels.$emit('updateBlocks')
            return

Vue.component 'article-content',
    template: '#article-content-template'
    props: ['uuid']
    data: ->
        {
            questions_blocks: []
            video_screens: []
        }
    mounted: ->
        @getBlocks()
        levels.$on 'updateBlocks', ->
            alert 'GOOOOOD'
            return
        return
    methods:
        getBlocks: ->
            _this = this
            $.get "/ajax/elements/#{@uuid}/load_blocks.json", (data) ->
                _this.questions_blocks = []
                _this.video_screens = []
                $.each data.questions_blocks, (i, questions_block) ->
                    _this.questions_blocks.push(questions_block)
                    return
                $.each data.video_screens, (i, video_screen) ->
                    _this.video_screens.push(video_screen)
                    return
                return
            return

levels = new Vue
    el: '#js-levels'
```

HTML:

```
#js-levels
    levels-list uuid="#{@element_level.uuid}" type="#{@element.my_type}"
    article-content uuid="#{@element_level.uuid}"
```

This code displays an error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: (found in )
>
> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'levels.$on')

**Why does this error occur?**

Also if I add `console.log` line:

```
mounted: ->
    @getBlocks()
    console.log levels
    levels.$on 'updateBlocks', ->
        alert 'GOOOOOD'
        return
    return
```

I will successfully receive the blocks. But the line `console.log levels` will return it: `undefined`. What is the problem?

Comment: `levels` is `undefined`?

Comment: You are accessing `levels` before it is defined. `levels` is defined at the bottom of your script. Move its definition upwards or just use `this.$on` or `this.$emit`. Using `this` is the recommended way to do this (see the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events))

Comment: @evolutionxbox If `levels` change to `window.levels` and call from browser console, but I successfully get the answer. Also this code works successfully: `switchLevel: (uuid) -> console.log levels`.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I tried and `this`, and `_this = this`. In these cases there is no error. But $emit and $on don't works.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I tried to implement the same as described in the documentation. I managed to establish a connection between `levels-list` and `switch-link`. `switch-link` - is a component of the reference document. In short, it did not lead to anything. The interaction with the `article-content` component could not be established.